# How to paste a small png behind a template in PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Good evening! I have been trying to make a script in PIL that pastes an image behind another image, like a meme template. The thing is - i can't find a way to get it on the back layer. Here i will provide examples for what i **want it to output** and **what it does**:

What i want it to output:
[image: An image of Scott Wozniak standing near a TV smiling with an image inside of the TV's display]

What it outputs:
[image: An image of Scott Wozniak standing near a TV smiling but the image from the example above is on the front layer]

And here's the code i use to generate the bottom image:

```py
url = ctx.message.attachments[0].url # Getting the image from Discord
pic = requests.get(url, stream=True).raw # Putting that image into the pic variable
template = Image.open("./generators/scott.png") # Opening the template with Scott into PIL
pic = Image.open(pic) # Opening the image from Discord
pic = pic.resize((565,402)) # Resizing the image to the size of the TV screen
template.paste(pic,(200,278)) # Pasting the image where it belongs
template.save("./renderedcontent/scott.png") # Saving the image to send it
```

**What i have tried:**

I tried browsing the docs for other functions, tried some, couldn't get stuff done with them, tried playing with variables and masks. Nothing worked, even got some funny renders out of it.

**TL;DR:**

I need to paste the image onto the back layer so it gets behind the big png template.

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't provide the actual template nor the image to put on. Ideally, the template has some transparency mask, e.g. for the exact cut-out of the TV. If not, you'd need to set up such a mask for proper pasting.

Comment: @HansHirse it has a cutout

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way possible I can' think off, if you don't mind perspective, is:

1. modify the big image template, cutting out with Photoshop or gimp the place where the image should be and saving it as PNG
2. Paste the meme on the canvas
3. Paste the big image on the canvas